# I am getting the following error while using Openai's whisper ai : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I've been trying to use OpenAI's whisper to transcribe some text.

I am using Openai's audio to text whisper ai API which also needs ffmpeg.
In the code I am trying to load and read the audio which uses ffmpeg and transcribe it.
While running the code I am getting an error. I think the error is occuring  in loading and reading the audio.
This is the code:

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")

# load audio and pad/trim it to fit 30 seconds
audio = whisper.load_audio(r"C:\Users\user\VS code projects\EH 12345.mp3")
audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio)

# make log-Mel spectrogram and move to the same device as the model
mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)

# detect the spoken language
_, probs = model.detect_language(mel)
print(f"Detected language: {max(probs, key=probs.get)}")

# decode the audio
options = whisper.DecodingOptions()
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)

# print the recognized text
print(result.text)
```

While running the above code I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\VS code projects\import whisper.py", line 6, in <module>
    audio = whisper.load_audio(r"C:\Users\user\VS code projects\EH 12345.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 42, in load_audio
    ffmpeg.input(file, threads=0)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I made sure that EH 12345.mp3 file exists and tried some other things but did not help.

Please Help Me to solve this problem.

Comment: I think the error is that the ffmpeg executable itself was not found.  Is it in your path?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **install ffmpeg-python** library and add it into **PATH**

first uninstall ffmpeg and ffmpeg-python if installed already

```
pip uninstall ffmpeg
pip uninstall ffmpeg-python
```

then install ffmpeg-python

```
pip install ffmpeg-python
```

then add this package into PATH as follows

[path_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBRjj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows), checked ffmpeg version on a new shell tab, and the reopened VScode to run my code. It worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34520011)

Answer (score 0):

it is connected with `ffmpeg` package. i think you need to install it.
the following is how to deal with it:
https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think you installed Whisper using `pip install whisper`. However, the [documentation](https://I%20think%20you%20installed%20Whisper%20using%20pip%20install%20whisper.%20However,%20the%20documentation%20mentions%20that%20you%20need%20to%20use%20pip%20install%20git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git%20to%20install%20it.) mentions that you need to use `pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git` to install it.